# How to apply a texture from a function in sfml

Tags: c++, c, file, textures, sfml

I am trying to apply a texture from a function but it doesn't seem to be working so how do I apply a texture to a function in sfml? I also get a error when I try to apply a texture from a function which is: button.h|18|error: no matching function for call to 'sf::RectangleShape::setTexture(sf::Texture&)'|. You can solve this problem by finding a way to apply a texture from a function or by fixing the error and it applies the texture. I have 2 files, one called main.cpp and another one called button.h. Here is their code.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "button.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
int main(){
    bool isStartOpen = false;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(500, 500), "Operating System", Style::Close | Style::Resize);
    RectangleShape player(Vector2f(500.0f, 30.0f));
    RectangleShape startMenu(Vector2f(300.0f, 400.0f));
    Texture startTexture;
    if(!startTexture.loadFromFile("startButton.png")){
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error loading image file: startButton.png in the system", "Image File Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    startMenu.setFillColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 200));
    startMenu.setPosition(0.0f, 500.0f);
    player.setFillColor(Color::Black);
    player.setPosition(0.0f, 473.0f);
    Font font;
    if(!font.loadFromFile("Calibri Regular.ttf")){
       MessageBox(NULL, "Error loading font file: buttonFont.ttf in the system", "Font File Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    Button openNotepad("Notepad", {90, 90}, 20, Color::Green, startTetxure);
    openNotepad.setPosition({100, 300});
    openNotepad.setFont(font);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch(event.type){
                case Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    cout << "Window has been removed" << endl;
                    break;
                case Event::MouseMoved:
                    if(openNotepad.isMouseOver(window)){
                        openNotepad.setBackColor(Color(42,150,83));
                        openNotepad.setOutThick(1.5);
                        openNotepad.setOutColor(Color(255, 255, 255, 100));
                    }else{
                        openNotepad.setBackColor(Color(0,110,51));
                        openNotepad.setOutThick(0);
                    }
                    break;
                case Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                    if(openNotepad.isMouseOver(window)){
                        cout << "You clicked the button" << endl;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Key::S) && !isStartOpen){
            startMenu.setPosition(0.0f, 75.0f);
            isStartOpen = true;
        }else{
            startMenu.setPosition(0.0f, 500.0f);
            isStartOpen = false;
        }
        window.draw(startMenu);
        window.draw(player);
        openNotepad.drawTo(window);
        window.display();
        window.clear(Color(1, 159, 255));
    }
}
}
```

**button.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
class Button{
    public:
        Button(){

        }
        Button(string t, Vector2f size, int charSize, Color bgColor, Texture &texture){
            text.setString(t);
            text.setColor(Color::White);
            text.setCharacterSize(charSize);
            text.setScale(0.7f, 0.7f);
            button.setSize(size);
            button.setFillColor(bgColor);
            button.setTexture(texture);
        }
        void setFont(Font &font){
            text.setFont(font);
        }
        void setBackColor(Color color){
            button.setFillColor(color);
        }
        void setTextColor(Color color){
            text.setColor(color);
        }
        void setPosition(Vector2f pos){
            button.setPosition(pos);
            float xPos = (pos.x + button.getLocalBounds().width / 30) - (text.getLocalBounds().width / 2);
            float yPos = (pos.y + button.getLocalBounds().height / 1.3) - (text.getLocalBounds().height / 2);
            text.setPosition({xPos, yPos});
        }
        void drawTo(RenderWindow &window){
            window.draw(button);
            window.draw(text);
        }
        void setOutColor(Color outColor){
            button.setOutlineColor(outColor);
        }
        void setOutThick(float outThick){
            button.setOutlineThickness(outThick);
        }
        bool isMouseOver(RenderWindow &window){
            float mouseX = Mouse::getPosition(window).x;
            float mouseY = Mouse::getPosition(window).y;
            float btnPosX = button.getPosition().x;
            float btnPosY = button.getPosition().y;
            float btnxPosWidth = button.getPosition().x + button.getLocalBounds().width;
            float btnyPosWidth = button.getPosition().y + button.getLocalBounds().height;
            if(mouseX < btnxPosWidth && mouseX > btnPosX && mouseY < btnyPosWidth && mouseY > btnPosY){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    private:
       RectangleShape button;
       Text text;
};
```

Comment: I don't need anymore answers because i already have a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us dissect the error.

> button.h|18|error: no matching function for call to 'sf::RectangleShape::setTexture(sf::Texture&)'

This means that you are trying to call a function that does not exist.

What function are we trying to call? It looks like we are trying to call the `setTexture` function inside of `sf::RectangleShape`.

Let's look at the [documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Shape.php#af8fb22bab1956325be5d62282711e3b6) for the function of the same name in `sf::RectangleShape`.

This function takes `const Texture* texture` as its first parameter. Let's look at the end of the error message again. It is trying to find a function that takes `sf::Texture&` as a parameter. The type it expects and the type you supply are different. `sf::Texture&` does not equal `const Texture*`, and there are no overloaded functions that take `sf::Texture&` as a parameter.

The solution is to get a `const Texture*` from a `sf::Texture&`.

The former is known as a pointer, (specifically a const pointer), and the latter is a reference (specifically a non-const reference).
You can get a pointer from a reference by using the address-of operator (`&`). So by calling `&texture` you can get the non-const pointer of the texture. The reverse can be done with the indirection operator (`*`).
A non-const pointer/reference can be implicitly changed to a const pointer/reference. This is one way and the reverse is not true.

Comment: It removed the error but it didn't apply the texture

Comment: If I fix my compiler's errors (calling of deprecated `sf::Text::setColor()`, and misspelling of `startTexture`) and use this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq2ZV.png texture for `startButton.png`, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLtP3.png, which is the texture applied to the button. Do you get different results?

Comment: Yes, on my notepad button, it has nothing on it

Comment: Can you show me your code to make that button

Comment: It is pretty much the exact same as your code except for the changes I mentioned. Here is a 7z file that has a Visual Studio Solution and an executable file in `/x64/Release/`: https://gist.github.com/JordanPowersUsername/d9ac64084350f7b2be296417459ea2d6/raw/ae9b2d9576367549b5ea14e3e0c272918480a8ad/Sandbox.7z. Extract it, run the executable to make sure it works (although be careful running stranger's executables), then compare the code. Your profile seems to indicate you use CodeBlocks and not Visual Studio so you probably can't open the Solution, but the IDE shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Ok, I finally figured out how to apply a texture from a function. Thanks for helping!